# Laravel - Illegal offset type when accessing property on OneToMany relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I'm learning how to use laravel and relationships. I'm having trouble accessing data from a hasMany relationship, I understand this might be a silly question. This might be a duplicate question, but I didn't find any specific answer like this.

I have two models, a salesman table and a prices table table. One salesman has many prices tables, so it's like this:

**On Salesman model**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Pedidos;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Vendedores extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'Pedidos';
    protected $primaryKey = 'CD_VENDEDOR';

    public function TabelaDePreco() {
        return $this->hasMany('\App\Pedidos\TabelaDePreco', 'CD_VENDEDOR', 'CD_VENDEDOR');
    }
}
```

**On the prices table model**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Pedidos;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class TabelaDePreco extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'Pedidos';
    protected $primaryKey = ['CD_VENDEDOR', 'CD_PRODUTO', 'CD_ESTADO'];

    public function Vendedores() {
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Pedidos\Vendedores', 'CD_VENDEDOR', 'CD_VENDEDOR');
    }

}
```

**On the Controller**

```php
public function index()
{
    $vendedores = Vendedores::all();
    return view('pedidos.tabeladepreco.index')
        ->with('title', 'Tabela de preços')
        ->with('vendedores', $vendedores);
}
```

**On the view, this will return TabelaDePreco model**

```php
@foreach($vendedores as $vendedor)
   @foreach ($vendedor->TabelaDePreco as $tabela)
       {{ dd($tabela) }}
   @endforeach
```

Here is a print from the code above:
[TabelaDePreco model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSPIf.png)

As you can see, data is loaded on the $tabela variable.

If I try to print, on the view, **{{ $tabela->NR_LIMITE1 }}**, I get the illegal offset type error. How do I access this attribute since data is loaded when using dd()? I've tried $tabela['NR_LIMITE1'] but with the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Best regards.

**EDIT:**

As pointed by Jonas on the comments, Laravel won't support relationships when one of the tables has composite keys. Back to migrations.

Comment: Laravel doesn't support composite primary keys. `Vendedores::$primaryKey` has to be a string.

Comment: Dear  Jonas, thanks for your reply. I've looked this up before posting, but since I'm querying only one of the keys I thought it might work. I'll keep searching about this matter. Regards.

Comment: Can you post the error's stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

You need to eager load your relation:

```
$vendedores = Vendedores::with('TabelaDePreco')->all();

    return view('pedidos.tabeladepreco.index')
        ->with('title', 'Tabela de preços')
        ->with('vendedores', $vendedores);
```

It may also happen that `$vendedor->TabelaDePreco` is not defined if there is not `TabelaDePreco` associated with the `$vendedor`. Try adding a `isset()`. Also thing about pagination if you have many entries.

Comment: Query\Builder::all does not exist. I tried using get() but it doesn't work neither, I can't dd($vendedores) because get() throws an error. Thanks for your response, now I have something to search for how to use properly. Pagination will be set indeed.